# SIGHUP signal triggered automatic shutdown of a Kafka Broker

Tags: apache-kafka

In our 3 broker Kafka Cluster, One of the Kafka broker was automatically shutdown. This happens to be a rare scenario as the same cluster runs without any issues.

As per the Kafka server.log, this particular broker recieved a SIGHUP signal which triggered an automatic shutdown.

After the broker was restarted it ran without an issue. What could be the issue which triggered the SIGHUP signal?

Below is the snippet from the kafka server.log

```
2020-03-18 14:01:07,570] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=RC-60-16] Writing producer snapshot at offset 9176994 (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2020-03-18 14:01:07,572] INFO [Log partition=RC-60-16, dir=/datafs3/kafka-logs] Rolled new log segment at offset 9176994 in 3 ms. (kafka.log.Log)
[2020-03-18 14:03:21,723] INFO Terminating process due to signal SIGHUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2020-03-18 14:03:21,729] INFO [KafkaServer id=1] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-03-18 14:03:21,731] INFO [KafkaServer id=1] Starting controlled shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-03-18 14:03:21,796] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 1] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(AL-60-0, FL-60-2, WL-60-55, WL-60-37, FL-60-47, RC-60-52, WL-60-19, FL-60-29, RC-60-34, FL-60-11, RC-60-16, FL-60-56, AL-60-42, CL-60-47, FL-60-38, AL-60-24, RC-60-43, CL-60-29, AL-60-6, RC-60-25, CL-60-11, RC-60-7, AL-60-51, WL-60-43, CL-60-56, AL-60-33, WL-60-25, CL-60-38, AL-60-15, WL-60-7, CL-60-20, WL-60-52, CL-60-2, WL-60-34, FL-60-44, RC-60-49, WL-60-16, FL-60-26, RC-60-31, FL-60-8, RC-60-13, FL-60-53, RC-60-58, FL-60-35, AL-60-21, RC-60-40, CL-60-26, FL-60-17, AL-60-3, RC-60-22, CL-60-8, RC-60-4, AL-60-48, CL-60-53, AL-60-30, WL-60-22, CL-60-35, AL-60-12, WL-60-4, CL-60-17, AL-60-57, WL-60-49, AL-60-39, WL-60-31, FL-60-41, CL-60-44, WL-60-13, FL-60-23, RC-60-28, FL-60-5, RC-60-10, WL-60-58, WL-60-40, FL-60-50, RC-60-55, FL-60-32, RC-60-37, FL-60-14, RC-60-19, CL-60-5, RC-60-1, FL-60-59, AL-60-45, CL-60-50, AL-60-27, RC-60-46, CL-60-32, AL-60-9, WL-60-1, CL-60-14, AL-60-54, WL-60-46, CL-60-59, AL-60-36, WL-60-28, CL-60-41, AL-60-18, WL-60-10, FL-60-20, CL-60-23) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2020-03-18 14:03:21,839] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 1] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(RC-60-20, WL-60-11, FL-60-15, WL-60-17, CL-60-45, CL-60-42, FL-60-6, FL-60-18, AL-60-46, AL-60-13, AL-60-20, AL-60-11, AL-60-16, WL-60-47, CL-60-36, RC-60-3, FL-60-36, AL-60-40, FL-60-45, FL-60-52, CL-60-21, WL-60-41, RC-60-53, FL-60-22, CL-60-9, RC-60-15, RC-60-59, WL-60-2, AL-60-17, CL-60-51, CL-60-1, AL-60-7, CL-60-55, FL-60-1, WL-60-18, CL-60-39, AL-60-58, FL-60-40, FL-60-58, WL-60-21, WL-60-29, RC-60-33, FL-60-49, FL-60-3, AL-60-19, FL-60-7, RC-60-21, WL-60-45, CL-60-4, CL-60-28, CL-60-25, AL-60-22, CL-60-12, RC-60-0, WL-60-6, FL-60-19, RC-60-11, RC-60-44, CL-60-57, CL-60-7, RC-60-5, WL-60-59, RC-60-14, CL-60-22, AL-60-8, RC-60-50, FL-60-46, RC-60-56, FL-60-12, FL-60-16, RC-60-47, AL-60-49, RC-60-26, AL-60-44, AL-60-41, CL-60-40, RC-60-39, WL-60-24, AL-60-31, CL-60-52, CL-60-0, WL-60-54, AL-60-55, AL-60-59, WL-60-0, CL-60-31, AL-60-34, FL-60-37, AL-60-25, AL-60-37, CL-60-18, RC-60-38, WL-60-30, AL-60-1, CL-60-43, FL-60-34, WL-60-50, WL-60-20, FL-60-30, RC-60-54, CL-60-54, WL-60-3, AL-60-50, CL-60-58, WL-60-44, WL-60-9, WL-60-36, AL-60-14, AL-60-29, AL-60-4, AL-60-38, WL-60-27, FL-60-25, RC-60-41, CL-60-49, RC-60-6, FL-60-4, FL-60-0, FL-60-13, FL-60-27, RC-60-8, WL-60-39, RC-60-27, CL-60-13, FL-60-9, AL-60-2, FL-60-43, FL-60-54, RC-60-17, RC-60-45, FL-60-24, AL-60-56, CL-60-48, AL-60-28, WL-60-33, WL-60-15, AL-60-26, WL-60-5, AL-60-23, RC-60-35, ML-1-0, WL-60-23, AL-60-35, FL-60-31, RC-60-23, WL-60-35, WL-60-57, FL-60-42, RC-60-57, RC-60-51, CL-60-19, CL-60-46, WL-60-14, CL-60-27, CL-60-6, RC-60-29, WL-60-51, WL-60-26, RC-60-36, RC-60-12, RC-60-2, CL-60-37, AL-60-32, CL-60-33, RC-60-9, WL-60-12, AL-60-5, WL-60-42, WL-60-56, AL-60-10, FL-60-33, CL-60-34, CL-60-30, RC-60-18, FL-60-10, FL-60-51, AL-60-53, WL-60-53, FL-60-28, AL-60-52, RC-60-42, AL-60-47, CL-60-15, WL-60-48, RC-60-24, WL-60-32, RC-60-48, CL-60-10, RC-60-32, CL-60-24, CL-60-16, AL-60-43, FL-60-39, CL-60-3, FL-60-21, WL-60-8, WL-60-38, FL-60-48, FL-60-55, RC-60-30, FL-60-57) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2020-03-18 14:03:21,839] INFO [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 1] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(RC-60-20, WL-60-11, FL-60-15, WL-60-17, CL-60-45, CL-60-42, FL-60-6, FL-60-18, AL-60-46, AL-60-13, AL-60-20, AL-60-11, AL-60-16, WL-60-47, CL-60-36, RC-60-3, FL-60-36, AL-60-40, FL-60-45, FL-60-52, CL-60-21, WL-60-41, RC-60-53, FL-60-22, CL-60-9, RC-60-15, RC-60-59, WL-60-2, AL-60-17, CL-60-51, CL-60-1, AL-60-7, CL-60-55, FL-60-1, WL-60-18, CL-60-39, AL-60-58, FL-60-40, FL-60-58, WL-60-21, WL-60-29, RC-60-33, FL-60-49, FL-60-3, AL-60-19, FL-60-7, RC-60-21, WL-60-45, CL-60-4, CL-60-28, CL-60-25, AL-60-22, CL-60-12, RC-60-0, WL-60-6, FL-60-19, RC-60-11, RC-60-44, CL-60-57, CL-60-7, RC-60-5, WL-60-59, RC-60-14, CL-60-22, AL-60-8, RC-60-50, FL-60-46, RC-60-56, FL-60-12, FL-60-16, RC-60-47, AL-60-49, RC-60-26, AL-60-44, AL-60-41, CL-60-40, RC-60-39, WL-60-24, AL-60-31, CL-60-52, CL-60-0, WL-60-54, AL-60-55, AL-60-59, WL-60-0, CL-60-31, AL-60-34, FL-60-37, AL-60-25, AL-60-37, CL-60-18, RC-60-38, WL-60-30, AL-60-1, CL-60-43, FL-60-34, WL-60-50, WL-60-20, FL-60-30, RC-60-54, CL-60-54, WL-60-3, AL-60-50, CL-60-58, WL-60-44, WL-60-9, WL-60-36, AL-60-14, AL-60-29, AL-60-4, AL-60-38, WL-60-27, FL-60-25, RC-60-41, CL-60-49, RC-60-6, FL-60-4, FL-60-0, FL-60-13, FL-60-27, RC-60-8, WL-60-39, RC-60-27, CL-60-13, FL-60-9, AL-60-2, FL-60-43, FL-60-54, RC-60-17, RC-60-45, FL-60-24, AL-60-56, CL-60-48, AL-60-28, WL-60-33, WL-60-15, AL-60-26, WL-60-5, AL-60-23, RC-60-35, ML-1-0, WL-60-23, AL-60-35, FL-60-31, RC-60-23, WL-60-35, WL-60-57, FL-60-42, RC-60-57, RC-60-51, CL-60-19, CL-60-46, WL-60-14, CL-60-27, CL-60-6, RC-60-29, WL-60-51, WL-60-26, RC-60-36, RC-60-12, RC-60-2, CL-60-37, AL-60-32, CL-60-33, RC-60-9, WL-60-12, AL-60-5, WL-60-42, WL-60-56, AL-60-10, FL-60-33, CL-60-34, CL-60-30, RC-60-18, FL-60-10, FL-60-51, AL-60-53, WL-60-53, FL-60-28, AL-60-52, RC-60-42, AL-60-47, CL-60-15, WL-60-48, RC-60-24, WL-60-32, RC-60-48, CL-60-10, RC-60-32, CL-60-24, CL-60-16, AL-60-43, FL-60-39, CL-60-3, FL-60-21, WL-60-8, WL-60-38, FL-60-48, FL-60-55, RC-60-30, FL-60-57) (kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager)
[2020-03-18 14:03:21,848] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=2, fetcherId=0] Shutting down (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2020-03-18 14:03:21,850] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=2, fetcherId=0] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=844786059, epoch=197425) to node 2: java.io.IOException: Client was shutdown before response was read. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
[2020-03-18 14:03:21,851] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=2, fetcherId=0] Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2020-03-18 14:03:21,851] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=2, fetcherId=0] Stopped (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2020-03-18 14:03:21,855] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=3, fetcherId=0] Shutting down (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2020-03-18 14:03:21,855] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=3, fetcherId=0] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=157379546, epoch=198831) to node 3: java.io.IOException: Client was shutdown before response was read. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
[2020-03-18 14:03:21,855] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=3, fetcherId=0] Stopped (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2020-03-18 14:03:21,855] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=3, fetcherId=0] Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2020-03-18 14:03:21,859] INFO [KafkaServer id=1] Controlled shutdown succeeded (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

---

In normal scenario, the kafka service is started with cron command as below:

```
10 06 * * 1,2,3,4,5 . $HOME/.bashrc; bash $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

But, in this case the service was run manually with the above same command without the 'nohup'. Does this lead to the controlling terminal being closed which triggers the SIGUP ?

Comment: How are you running Kafka? e.g. System service? Docker? Manually from the command line?

Comment: Hey  Robin, I am running Kafka as a system service from 3 different physical server machines.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP):

> On POSIX-compliant platforms, SIGHUP ("signal hang up") is a signal sent to a process when its controlling terminal is closed. (It was originally designed to notify the process of a serial line drop.) SIGHUP is a symbolic constant defined in the header file signal.h.

So something is telling the Kafka process to shutdown. If it's running as a system service then perhaps the system as a whole is rebooting? You might want to check the machine's syslog for indications that a reboot has been triggered.

---

Edit: Yes, the scenario you describe (*the service was run manually, without the `nohup`*) is *exactly* what would cause this. The `nohup` means: don't send a `SIGHUP` when this shell ends. Without that, a `SIGHUP` is sent and the process shuts down.

Comment: In normal scenario, the kafka service is started with cron command as below:                     10 06 * * 1,2,3,4,5 . $HOME/.bashrc; bash $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties > /dev/null 2>&1 &                                                                                But, in this case the service was run manually with the above same command without the 'nohup'.   Does this lead to the controlling terminal being closed which triggers the SIGUP ?